# Can you tell exactly what a request is?

Tags: google-maps, action

What are the actions that can be described as requests when the map in my website is used by a visitor? For example: if the user is zooming in or out, is this a request on the map?
Thank you

Comment: if you mean request for usage quota  .. zoom  no ...  a normal request is the loading of  google js library .. others request are for each geocoding  and other for others service  .. each service is calculated  separately

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload) states:

> A single map load is charged when any of the following occur:
>
> - A web page or application displays a map using the Google Maps JavaScript API.
>
> After a web page or application loads a map, a static map image, or a Street View panorama, **any user interactions with it, such as panning, zooming, or switching map layers, do not generate additional map loads or affect usage limits.**